# How to add button by default in WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple WordPress website and a code snippet of a button.
What i want is, whenever i create a new WordPress Post, i want that particular piece of button code to appear in my new POST by default. 
I tried to hard-code it to my WordPress post file but its not working. 
This is what i tried so far,

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = "If you like this post, then please consider retweeting it or sharing it on Facebook.";
    return $content;
}
```

It works but only for textual data and not for HTML.
Any guideline will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you tried in code so far

Comment: Kindly check the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the_content filter, here is how:

```
function add_button_to_all_posts($content) {
  return $content."If you like this post, then please consider retweeting it or sharing it on Facebook. <a href='yourlink'>button here</a>";
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_button_to_all_posts' );
```